# How To install hybridauth in a project that is on a server?

Tags: php, session, server

I have a project locally and I installed `hybridauth` to login with social networks, but now I uploaded it to a test server and my problem is that I do not know how to install `hybridauth` to the project that is already uploaded in the server.

locally I installed composer to install the `hybridauth` library, I went to the terminal and referred to the location of my project, then I put this command to install hybridauth: `composer require hybridauth / hybridauth`